# yum install activemq activemq-client - no package activemq available

Tags: activemq-classic, redhat, yum

I am trying to install activemq and activemq-client on RHEL 6.6 with yum.
But after typing

```
yum install activemq activemq-client
```

the machine just saying

```
No package activemq available
No package activemq-client available
Nothing to do.
```

Is there a way to get yum working for this ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are there RPMs for those packages that you are aware of? What repository are those supposed to be coming from?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't know... I was following a tutorial which said to use "yum install activemq activemq-client" but it does not work, so I don't really know what to do now :-/

Comment: What tutorial? Was it for RHEH 6.6? Did it ask you to set up any extra repositories that you perhaps skipped?

Comment: [link](https://blog.openshift.com/installing-enterprise-paas-part-2/) The Tutorial is for installing enterprise open shift, which should be installed on RHEL 6.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple installation following the tutorial you have to enable different repos for yum, this can be done by

```
subscription-manager repos --enable=*repoid*
```

To get a list of Repo IDs, you can use:

```
subscription-manager repos --list
```

After this, everything works fine.